# pie chart with rotation features in android os using achartengine library

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

I draw one pie chart using the `achartengine` library.  I want to rotate that view with respect to centre of pie chart. How to rotate this view section by section?

Comment: You should show what you have tried until now and describe what errors you experienced.

Comment: I created one pie view.now i want to make that view interactive.According to interaction rotate one by one section and showing value.

Comment: You should post the relevant code you already have, your error and eventually your logcat. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I don't have rotation relevent code. i just draw pie chart using achartengine library

Comment: https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart i want this type of interaction in achartengine pie or donut view